# Symsquare Number 03

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues

Symsquare5: The answer is a square grid which has the same words vertically and horizontally. The clue is a single sentence written in cryptic style and includes one anagram, one hidden word, one Charade, one straight clue and one Double Meaning, all as syntactically separate units.

> The article particle collision resulted in a clean mess that the fifth Hal and St Crispin orator could discourage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution

> ```
>  C L A S H
>  L A N C E
>  A N I O N
>  S C O U R
>  H E N R Y
> ```

Charade

> *"The article particle"*
>  **ANION** =  AN (article) + ION (particle)

Straight Clue

> *"collision"*
>  **CLASH**

Anagram

> *"clean mess"*
>  **LANCE** = anagram of *clean*

Double Meaning

> *"fifth Hal and St Crispin orater"*
>  **HENRY** = Henry V (Prince Hal is the term used for Shakespeare's Henry V who also gives the St Crispin's Day speech).

Hidden word

> *"could discourage"*
>  **SCOUR** is hidden in diSCOURage